# Problem solving definite integral the F(b)-F(a) method

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

[This is my attempt at the problem](http://i949.photobucket.com/albums/ad332/Fractur65/DSCN0308.jpg), must have made some small error with the antiderivative of with my addition/multiplication somewhere but I'm just not seeing it right now. Just need a fresh set of eyes to look at it I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not squaring the third monomial in your equations a and b.
 (After you've plugged in 2 and 0 respectively)

Answer (score 2):

Your steps are correct and so is your indefinite integral. You seemed to have made a mistake at the arithmetic part.
\begin{equation}
3(2)^4 - 2(2)^3 +2(2)^2 - 2 = 48 - 16 + 8 - 2 = 38
\end{equation}